# Where can I see if my chrome extension is enabled without opening the browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension loaded into my Google Chrome and I’d like to be able to tell whether it is enabled or not without having to open Chrome and go to the extensions page.  Is there a way to do that?

If that matters, the extension is located in the `appdata/local/Google/chrome/default/extensions` folder.

Comment: You can parse `Preferences` file in the browser profile directory, which is a standard JSON. If you pretty-format it you'll see each extension has a ”state” property.

Comment: @wOxxOm yep that would do it!  Wanna put it into an answer?

Comment: IDK, there's a somewhat related answer: [How do I enable/disable google chrome extensions via console](//stackoverflow.com/a/6287432)